# How to center the text in the list of the QComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

a similar  question  is already answered here: [How to center text in QComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770287/how-to-center-text-in-qcombobox)

but  still I cant  find  a method how  to center the  items  shown  in  the list?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.combo.setEditable(True)
        self.combo.lineEdit().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.combo.addItems('One Two Three Four Five'.split())
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to use a delegate:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class AlignDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(AlignDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        delegate = AlignDelegate(self.combo)
        self.combo.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.combo.setEditable(True)
        self.combo.lineEdit().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.combo.addItems('One Two Three Four Five'.split())
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: but  what  if  the combobox should not be  editable ...  because  if  I set  it  afterwars  to setEditable(False)  then it  is  again  on the left  side ..

Comment: With PyQt5 you can use self.combo.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True) which should make is to the text is not editable  (did not test with PqQt4).